# Get foreign key with php (syntax)

Tags: php, html, sql

I have the two tables

```
Create TABLE Comment(
    CommentText TEXT,
    CommentDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Time time,
    PostedBy VARCHAR(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (PostedBy) REFERENCES Employee(Name)
);

Create TABLE Employee(
 Name VARCHAR(30),
 Title VARCHAR(30),
 Onshift BOOLEAN,
 PRIMARY KEY(Name)
);
```

Now how can I do the following

```
$Comments =     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comment");
$all_comments = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Comments)) {
    $all_comments[] = $row;
}

foreach($all_comments as $commentrow){
    if($commentrow['PostedBy']){ //Check if The Employee is Onshift 
        Echo("The employee was on shift");
    }
    else{
        Echo("The employee was on shift");
    }
}
```

I.E given the foreign key (postedby) lookup another value in that foregin keys table (in this case if the boolean if the staff is on shift?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select should be something like

```
SELECT c.*, e.Name, e.Onshift FROM Comment as c join Employee as e on c.PostedBy = e.Name
```

And then you can just use

```
$commentrow['Onshift']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this comment anyone of sql and test your code

```
//Priority on comment table 

$sql = "SELECT cmd.*, emp.* FROM Comment AS cmd
LEFT JOIN employee AS emp ON cmd.name = emp.name";

//use anyone of thsi based on ur need

$sql = "SELECT cmd.*, emp.* FROM Comment AS cmd
LEFT JOIN employee AS emp ON emp.name = cmd.name";

$Comments =     mysql_query($sql);
$all_comments = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Comments)) {

 if($row['PostedBy']){ //Check if The Employee is Onshift 
    echo("The employee was on shift");
 }
 else{
   echo("The employee was not in shift");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, wish I could accept both your answers :/